# Item Cannot added in to the jList

Tags: java, swing

i am creating simple inventry system in Java.when i add the productname,price,qty click add button product information should added into the JList.how it didn't added. got the Error.

**java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JList$3 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel**

```
 DefaultListModel model;
 String panme = (txtpname.getText());
                int price = Integer.parseInt(txtprice.getText());
                int qty = Integer.parseInt(txtqty.getText());
                int tot = qty * price;
            
                 
                model = (DefaultListModel)jList1.getModel();
                
                model.addElement(new Object[]
                        {
                            panme ,
                            price,
                            qty,
                            tot, 
                        });
        }
```

Comment: You need to cast using ``(DefaultListModel)(jList1.getModel())``, otherwise you are attempting to cast the ``jList`` as a DefaultListModel rather than the full expression.

Comment: i did it  but i didn't add the data to to list can u add the full code for that

Comment: Please read a Swing tutorial, specifically focusing on their uses of the JList and the ListModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a `JList` an empty constructor or using an Array or Vector, then a read only `ListModel` is created.

If you want to be able to modify the `ListModel` then you need to specifically add a `DefaultListModel` to the `JList`:

```
JList list = new JList( new DefaultListModel() );
```

Then in your above method you will be able to access the model as a `DefaultListModel`.

Having said that, you should NOT be using a `JList` for this since you are adding multiple properties. Instead you should use a `JTable` which allows you to add data that you can display in rows/columns.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.

Comment: i know JTable i need Jlist how to load please add the code

Comment: A JList is designed to display a single item on each row. If you are trying to add 4 rows of data, then you need to invoke the `addElement(...)` method 4 times, once for the *name*, once for the "price" etc.